# Why does this code not cause a mouse event to fire?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using selenium/chromedriver and the code below.

I would expect to see in the console log the mouse event as I do when I run  MoveToElement with other elements.

Why does this not work with the body of websites?

```
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.brenz.net/snippets/xy.asp");
IJavaScriptExecutor jx = (IJavaScriptExecutor)driver;
jx.ExecuteScript("mousePosX =  0; mousePosY = 0; onmousemove = function(e){ mousePosX = e.clientX; mousePosY = e.clientY; console.log('Y:' + mousePosY + ' X:' + mousePosX); }; ");

var bodyTag = driver.FindElement(By.TagName("body"));
var actionDriver = new Actions(driver);
actionDriver.MoveToElement(bodyTag, 200, 200);
```

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't using .perform()

```
actionDriver.MoveToElement(bodyTag, 200, 200).Perform();
```